# Unable to import import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport

Tags: android, jar, google-api-java-client

I am unable to import `com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport`

I have tried downloading all dependencies from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/download

And then adding them to my project by
 
Project > Open Module Settings >  Dependencies > + > File Dependency > `google-api-client-android-1.20.0.jar` > OK

With no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Copy the `google-http-client-1.20.0.jar` to `app/libs`

[image]

- Add `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` to your `app/build.gradle` in `dependencies`.
- Go to `Tools --> Android--> Sync project with Gradle files`.

Now you can import the class:)

[image]